about ffmpeg option atomic_writing used in segment output
I made a ffmpeg command like this:
ffmpeg -y -i ./test.mp4 -ar 16000 -ac 1 -acodec pcm_s16le -f segment -segment_format s16le -segment_time 5 -vn -copyts -frame_pts true -atomic_writing true ./files/%d.pcm".

This command runs ok;
But in my usage, I have aother thread scan the files dir looply when the command is running, if found new file, open it, read it, but sometimes, file opend, but read 0 bytes from the file.
so, I want to know, if the atomic_writing option take effective?
or only effect for output'type is image?
If the option is no effect here, any other idea can archive my purpose?
thank you!

In the documentation, atomic_writing is under image2 muxer. ffmpeg -h muxer=image2 shows atomic_writing option and ffmpeg -h muxer=segment doesn't. -atomic_writing true probably has no effect when used with segment muxer.

I think that we can follow the generated segment list. Executing the following command for example: ffmpeg -re -y -hide_banner -loglevel error -i audio.mp4 -ar 16000 -ac 1 -acodec pcm_s16le -f segment -segment_format s16le -segment_time 5 -vn -copyts -frame_pts true -segment_list pipe:1 "%03d.pcm", prints the output file name every 5 seconds. I guess that it is printed after the segment output file is closed. Maybe there is a better solution, but scanning the files is probably not the recommended way.
